# How to handle client disconnection in RabbitMQ RPC?

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc, distributed

I want to handle a situation in [RabbitMQ RPC](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-go.html) when a client is disconnected that way: server checks that response queue exists and if it doesn't - cancel current task.
So I have few questions:

- does this solution look good? (i have some undescribable doubts about that)
- what is the way to perform this check? (i found only able to check response queue existence via RabbitMQ HTTP API)

Comment: Use of the mandatory and immediate flags would be appropriate in this case.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you. Flags of what?

Comment: Wait, are you saying you want to check *before* you start processing?

Comment: No, check while processing

Comment: What if the RPC client has sent out 100 jobs. And waiting for 100 responses. And in the middle the client goes down. Does that mean we would need to run all of those jobs again or is there a way to make it persist?